# Reason why PNG figure is empty and solutions

Tags: r

I have the following function in R

```
pairwise.yearly.plot <- function(data.source, data.target, suffix=".PR", years=2003:2007) {
  # plot pairwise year data for time series representation of data                                                                                                                                                                 
  first <- years[1]
  last <- years[length(years)]
  nc <- last - first #2007-2003                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  par(mfrow=c(nc, nc))
  for(y1 in years) {
    for(y2 in years) {
      if(y1 < y2) {
        year.source <- num.to.colname(y1);
        if(suffix == ".PE") {
          year.target <- paste(num.to.colname(y1), y2, sep=".");
        } else {
          year.target <- paste(num.to.colname(y2), suffix, sep="");
        }
        plot(data.source[[year.source]], data.target[[year.target]], xlab=y1, ylab=paste(y2, suffix,sep=""))
      }
      else if(y1 > y2) {
        frame()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I invoke this with:

```
png("output.png")
pairwise.yearly.plot(foo, bar)
dev.off()
```

I get an empty png file. This doesn't happen when I set the graphic device to pdf. Could anybody tell me why and how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal data set so that we can actually run your function with data that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Try `nc <- length(years)`

Comment: If you just run pairwise.yearly.plot(foo, bar), without the png("output") and dev.off(), does a plot show up?

Comment: @kith Yup, it shows up. And with pdf(...) also. Just not png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling more plot commands than you've prepared for with par(mfrow=c(nc, nc))

if nc is 4, then you're prepping 16 cells to draw on, but the loops account for 25 operations.  If the last of those extra operations is frame() you'll end up with a blank picture.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Thanks! I changed the for loops to: `for(y1 in years[1:nc]) { for(y2 in years) {` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `ggplot`, use this template:

```
png("PNG_FILE.png")
g <- ggplot(....)
print(g)
dev.off()
```